# QDbus: Service Call Returning QList<int>

Tags: c++, qt, pidgin, qdbus

I'm running into difficulty retrieving values from a service call that is supposed to return an array of integers.  The method call in the interface xml file is defined as:

```
<method name="PurpleFindBuddies">
    <annotation name="org.qtproject.QtDBus.QtTypeName.Out0" value="QList&lt;int>"/>
    <arg name="accountId" type="i" direction="in" />
    <arg name="screenName" type="s" direction="in" />
    <arg name="buddies" type="ai" direction="out" />
</method>
```

qdbusxml2cpp generates the following method:

```
 inline QDBusPendingReply<QList<int> > PurpleFindBuddies(int accountId, const QString &screenName)
{
    QList<QVariant> argumentList;
    argumentList << QVariant::fromValue(accountId) << QVariant::fromValue(screenName);
    return asyncCallWithArgumentList(QLatin1String("PurpleFindBuddies"), argumentList);
}
```

I have also added

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QList<int>)
```

at the top of the generated .h file.  And in main.cpp, I'm making the following call

```
QDBusPendingReply<QList<int> > buddies = pidgin->PurpleFindBuddies(accountId, "email@gmail.com");
buddies.waitForFinished();

if ( buddies.isError() ) {
    qDebug() << buddies.error();
    return -1;
}

qDebug() << buddies.argumentAt(0).toList().size();
```

When I launch the program, I can see from the enabled debug output that I am getting results, as shown below, but the qDebug() line prints 0.  I cannot figure out how to correctly retrieve the results.

```
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x138fbc0) got message reply (async): QDBusMessage(type=MethodReturn, service=":1.135", signature="ai", contents=([Argument: ai {859}]) )
```

What am I missing?  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently everything was configured correctly.  However, when trying to retrieve the data, instead of doing:

```
qDebug() << buddies.argumentAt(0).toList().size();
```

I should have been doing:

```
qDebug() << QString::number(buddies.value().size());
```

To retrieve the individual ids

```
foreach(int id, buddies.value() )
    qDebug() << QString::number(id);
// or simply
QList<int> ids = buddies.value();
```